# Do closed questions go to a virtual land-fill and can they be seen?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I ask questions now and then, and sometimes they are closed. At times I wanna re-visit my closed questions but don't know where to look at those. This is to improve the closed question and well, to ask the people who closed my question to have another look.

Can someone elaborate?

Also if questions are closed and after some days they are deleted, is there a time-frame for it? If yes, what is the time-frame and is the whole thing documented somewhere?

Comment: One of measures to safeguard a question against auto-deletion as non-interesting is marking it favourite (a star).

Answer (score 7):

Closed questions are still accessible to anyone. You can use a couple search filters to find [your own closed questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:50490+closed:yes):

- `user:50490` (or `user:me`) will show only your posts
- `closed:yes` will show only closed questions

If you've edited an old question and think it should be reopened, [vote to reopen it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) and it will show up in a review queue so other users can check it and vote as well.

Automatic deletion of questions is documented [on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Comment: OK, I’m confused.  [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/195817) indicates that some questions are deleted automatically when they get to be 365 days old, *and some get deleted after 30 days*.  This, or something similar, (still) seems to be in effect — I have >10K on Super User (so I can see deleted posts), and I occasionally stumble across questions that have been deleted automatically because they’ve been “abandoned”, and I’m pretty sure that they generally aren’t more than 60 days old.

Comment: @Scott Didn't know about that; edited

Comment: Are you sure they're visible to new users who didn't create the question, too? It seems that some stuff like this isn't, whether or not deleted questions are. Higher reputation seems to increase what you can see on StackExchange (I'm not sure if it's different for different sites on it).

Comment: @Shule Closed questions are visible even if you're not logged in, I just tried with [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165582/can-somebody-list-the-earliest-public-source-code-repositories-and-when-they-ope). Reputation affects deleted questions (they're visible to 10k users because they can [vote to undelete](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), but not closed questions